# Перебор input'ов в форме

Tags: jquery

Есть форма. При нажатии на кнопку проверяем заполнены ли все поля и если да, то подгружаем следующую страницу. Так вот вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы если хотя бы одно поле пустое, то не прогружать следующую страницу. Пока получилось только так. Но если задавать и, то как только попадется не пустой инпут, то выполнится **else** условие. А мне нужно не первый попавшийся а именно проверка каждого, и если хотя бы один из них пустой, выполнить **else**. Условие **else** в моем случае это то, что начинается с **$.ajax** и дальше него.

```js
$('.to-second-next').on("click", function() {
  $('.stages-form').find('input.field').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      alert('Заполните поле ' + '"' + $(this).attr("name") + '"');
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "registration-stage-two.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#full-reg-content").html(html);
    }
  });

  $(this).css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  $('.to-third-next').css({
    'display': 'inline-block'
  });
  $('.to-first-prev').css({
    'display': 'inline-block'
  });

  $lastname_inp = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();
  $firstname_inp = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
  $patronymic_inp = $('input[name="patronymic"]').val();
  $phone_number_inp = $('input[name="phone-number"]').val();
  $mobile_number_inp = $('input[name="mobile-number"]').val();
  $skype_inp = $('input[name="skype"]').val();
  $born_place_inp = $('input[name="born-place"]').val();
  $birth_date_inp = $('input[name="birth-date"]').val();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var hasEmptyFields = false;
$('.stages-form').find('input.field').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    hasEmptyFields = true;
    alert('Заполните поле ' + '"' + $(this).attr("name") + '"');
  }
});
if (hasEmptyFields)
  return false;
```

Comment: Но теперь при заполнении всех полей при нажатии на кнопку далее переход на след стр. не срабатывает(((

Comment: @zh-mskl9 - срабатывает, это Вы неправильно код скопировали.

Comment: Я просто переменную объявлял вне функции. Но почему тогда в таком случае эта конструкция не видит hasEmptyFields как глобальную переменную?